# How to integrate PDFTRON SDK in macOS App with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, pdftron

I am working on the iOS app. But new in macOS App.
Does anyone help me who worked on PDFTRON?
I want to integrate PDFTRON into my macOS APP, but I Don't know how to do it.

PDFTRON SDK link https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/mac/get-started/obj-c/

I tried all the steps given on that page but those are not worked.

Comment: PDFTron does offer Mac Catalyst PDF SDK which can be used to build a MacOS application. See more from the like here: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/mac/catalyst/ Is this something you can use in your application?

Comment: thank you @ShakthiWijeratne for your comment, But sir I want to use only macOS with ObjC.